# Not able to save social media signin in cognito identity pool

Tags: android, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have integrated facebook Sign In in my application and I am using Cognito for SignUp and Login Process. I have successfully received the token from Facebook and as per Cognito Documentation I can add that user into Identity pool of Cognito By Adding this piece of code in Amazon Cognito credentials provider.

```
Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
logins.put("graph.facebook.com",  
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```

But I am not getting the user token on Cognito by applying this code. I made **credentialsProvider** object of **AwsCredentialsProvider**. Is it the right way of doing this.Where do i need to enter the Identity pool Id.I am clueless about this even after going through the whole documentation.